# Instagram media search: the larger the radius I get less results... is this possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using the instagram media search to display posts on a map. In order to optimise this, I'm requesting a certain radius of a location and check the user stays within that area. The problem is that the larger the radius, I get less posts.

I read in the documentation that the max distance is 5km, but I can't find anywhere that there is a restriction in the amount of results you get from the service.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is a problem with that. 1km radius gives the best results, I gave up using other radius values a long ago :) Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can get up to 100 photos with one request.
See example here https://instmap.com/?distance=500 (you can change `radius` parameter and test the results)

Answer (score 0):

Each api response will return about 20 photos, you have to use pagination to get more photos.

Here is an implementation: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map
You can select a location on map and radius to search for photos, you can compare your results